# How To Implement IoC Containers in MVC Web Application with E.F

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inversion-of-control

I am trying to wrap my head around IoC containers. As I delve deeper into this design pattern I come across multitudes of abstraction layers, interfaces and concrete classes when before I was simply instantiating a data-context class, using it and then disposing of it.

Whilst I am keen to continue forward there are some outstanding issues I don't know how to resolve and would like some clarification and guidance.

1. In a generic web application with 2 projects (mvc web & data layer
   containing e.f.), if our dependancy resolver expects a repository
   that implements a specific interface (allowing us to switch
   repositories at any time in the future), where is this interface
   defined?  I dont see how it can be defined in the mvc web project because then the data access layer will become dependant on it and it cannot reside in the data access layer as then the mvc project depends on the dal and i've missed the whole point of this excercise.  So is
   the answer to define it in both projects and have each project
   reference its own copy? ..Is that even possible? Or do i need to
   create a third service layer project and stick one interface
   declaration in it and have both projects reference this?
2. Ive seen a number of articles talking about Unity IoC with
   interfaces such as IProductRepository, IClientRepository and
   IProductService, IClientService (this is what I was referring to in
   my opening paragraph). Am I correct in assuming that each of these
   instances is supposed to reference a table in my database? If so
   what happens if i have 50 tables? do i need to create 50 repository
   interfaces and 50 table related interfaces just to decouple everything?
   And how does using EF with POCO classes impact things? do i need to
   have each POCO implement its own specified interface?

thanks

Comment: Do not confuse logical layers (presentation, data, business) with physical layers (mvc project/assembly, data). An app can be in one physical assembly, and still be structured logically in separate layers that do not talk directly to eachother, where components are injected where necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would split your solution into several projects.

You would have a contracts project where your interfaces are defined, a dal where a concrete version of those interfaces are implemented.

Your mvc project would then reference the contracts project to handle the references to the types.

You would use an IOC container to scan the assemblies in the bin folder and find a concrete implementation of the dependencies for your controller.  This means that you would build your dal into the bin folder of your mvc project.  This means you can switch the dal out for other implementations simply by placing a new dll in the bin folder.

As for the repositories and tables, I tend to group them by business function.  So a business function of managing users and their related tables would be in a user repository etc.  but that is down to personal preference imo.

Answer (score 0):

When you are breaking your project into tiers you are correct in not wanting your data layer to rely on a project further up the stack. In general you want these dependencies to be unidirectional. You can either continue what you are doing and put the interfaces in the data layer, or you can create a new project to house the model code, including the repository and service interfaces. Your data layer would depend on the model code, and your mvc layer will depend on the data layer.

To address your second question I would say this is where the art of design comes in. You don't necessarily want a one to one mapping between your entities and your data tables. If it makes sense and you believe it's manageable, especially with the help of Entity Framework, then go ahead with the one to one mapping. But keep in mind that the responsibilities of the persistence layer and the domain model layer are different. If the persistence layer starts to bog down your work creating the domain model then it's time to put some work into separating the two.

More important are the interface 'facades' that are going to be exposed to the mvc project. These are going to require some degree of decoupling from the model and persistence layers. They should be distilled down to the core responsibilities of the model. You don't want to clutter your application layer with the intricacies of your domain model.

Comment: Why would the MVC layer depend on the data layer? If you are doing that for any other reason than getting the compiled assembly in the bin output folder, then you are doing it for the wrong reasons.